# Steal the resource of cv::Mat to IplImage

Tags: c++, c, opencv

below is the source codes of copying the resource of cv::Mat into the IplImage

```
//copy the resource of src into IplImage
void copy_mat_Ipl(cv::Mat const &src, IplImage **dst)
{
         IplImage* old = *dst;
        IplImage temp_src = src;
        *dst = cvCloneImage(&temp_src);
        cvReleaseImage(&old);
}
```

but I don't want to copy it, what I want is steal the resource from cv::Mat
I have to steal it, because the cv::Mat could be a local object in a function
If I don't steal it but do something like this

```
void move_mat_to_Ipl(cv::Mat &src, IplImage **dst)
{
         IplImage* old = *dst;            
        **dst = src;
        cvReleaseImage(&old);
}

void some_function(IplImage **dst)
{
   cv::Mat src;
   //do something
   move_mat_to_Ipl(src, dst);
}
```

The resource of src will be free, then dst will hold a dangling pointer
How could I steal the resource of cv::Mat?

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change the `move_mat_to_Ipl function`

```
IplImage ** move_mat_to_Ipl(cv::Mat &src, IplImage **dst)
{
    IplImage* old = *dst;
    IplImage temp_src = src;
    **dst = src;
    cvReleaseImage(&old);

    return **dst;
}
```

This will [return](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/functions/) the **dst and then you are able to pass it into the other function